# Calculate sum of rows with the same value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a project right now that will calculate the value for all rows based on the value of the first cell in the row. Right now my data will look like this:

[image]

The goal here is to have any room name automatically create a new row with the title of the room and calculate the total of that room and fill out the cell adjacent to it. Similar to this
[image]

What would be the best method of going about this in just plain excel. I am creating this as an ingest template for my team to work in but I'm not sure how this would be done with just simple formulas.

Comment: [`SUMIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)?

Comment: Or `SUMIFS()` ?

Comment: SUMIF() would work if I knew what values were going to be in room names but I will never know the names of the rooms put here and how many rows will be used for each room

Comment: If the data is manually populated, you can put it in an Excel table. If you have Microsoft 365, a single formula, using `HSTACK`, `UNIQUE`, and `FILTER` (or `XLOOKUP`), could spill the desired values. If not, there is a `LOOKUP` formula to get the unique room numbers in the first column and a `SUMIF` formula to get the sum in the second column.  Please let us know if any of it could work for you.

Comment: @JayPee Yes possible with ***Microsoft-365***. You can do that by a single cell formula. Means, formula will automatically detect new entries and include then to your result without manually updating formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following formula-

```
=VSTACK(HSTACK("Room No","Total"),
LET(x,A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),
HSTACK(UNIQUE(x),SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,UNIQUE(x)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Much more cleaner approach `=VSTACK(HSTACK("Room","Total"),UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2:A10,SUMIFS(E2:E10,A2:A10,A2:A10))))`.

Comment: This method works for me but for some reason when I implement it it only counts the second to last value. For example, if I have 112,113,114, and 115. It will calculate them all except 115. This is my adjusted formula =VSTACK(HSTACK("Room No","Total"),
LET(x,A4:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),
HSTACK(UNIQUE(x),SUMIFS(F:F,A:A,UNIQUE(x)))))

Comment: I assume you have blank cells before A4. If it, then you have adjust the formula little more. Try this, `=VSTACK(HSTACK("Room No","Total"), LET(x,A4:INDEX(A4:A50000,COUNTA(A4:A50000)), HSTACK(UNIQUE(x),SUMIFS(F:F,A:A,UNIQUE(x)))))`